# How about writing test code for the viewmodel below?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing, mockito

I created a view model to handle authentication (login and register), but I'm having trouble writing unit testing code. Can anyone help me write unit testing code for the view model below?

### Authentication View Model :

```kotlin
class AuthenticationViewModel(private val userRepository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
    var user = MutableLiveData<Event<UserModel>>()

    var loading = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()

    var message = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()

    var error = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()

    fun userLogin(email: String, password: String): MutableLiveData<Event<UserModel>> {
        loading.value = Event(true)
        val client = userRepository.userLogin(email, password)
        client.enqueue(object : Callback<UserResponse> {
           override fun onResponse(
               call: Call<UserResponse>,
               response: Response<UserResponse>
            ) {
                Log.e("AuthenticationViewModel", "onResponse: " + response.body())
                loading.value = Event(false)
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val responseBody = response.body()?.loginResult
                    error.value = Event(false)
                    userRepository.appExecutors.networkIO.execute {
                        Log.e("AuthenticationViewModel", "userLogin: $responseBody")
                        user.postValue(Event(responseBody!!))
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("AuthenticationViewModel", "onResponse fail: ")
                    message.value = Event(response.message())
                    error.value = Event(true)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("AuthenticationViewModel", "onFailure: " + t.message)
                loading.value = Event(false)
                message.value = Event(t.message.toString())
                error.value = Event(true)
            }
        })
        return user
    }

    fun userRegister(
        name: String,
        email: String,
        password: String
    ) {
        loading.value = Event(true)
        val client = userRepository.userRegister(name, email, password)
        client.enqueue(object : Callback<UserResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<UserResponse>,
                response: Response<UserResponse>
            ) {
                Log.e("AuthenticationViewModel", "onResponse: " + response.body())
                loading.value = Event(false)
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    error.value = Event(false)
                } else {
                    Log.e("AuthenticationViewModel", "onResponse fail: ")
                    message.value = Event(response.message())
                    error.value = Event(true)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("AuthenticationViewModel", "onFailure: " + t.message)
                loading.value = Event(false)
                message.value = Event(t.message.toString())
                error.value = Event(true)
            }
        })
    }

    fun getUserToken() = userRepository.getUserToken()

    fun saveUserToken(token: String?) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (token != null) {
                userRepository.saveUserToken(token)
            }
        }
    }

    fun saveUserName(name: String?) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (name != null) {
                userRepository.saveUserName(name)
            }
        }
    }

    fun saveUserEmail(email: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userRepository.saveUserEmail(email)
        }
    }

    fun logout() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userRepository.clearCache()
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried to write unit testing code, but failed and encountered a **NullPointerException**

### AuthenticationViewModelTest :

```kotlin
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class AuthenticationViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var repository: UserRepository
    private lateinit var viewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
    private val dummyUser = DataDummy.generateDummyUser()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        viewModel = AuthenticationViewModel(repository)
    }

    @Test
    fun `when userLogin should return user response when email and password are valid and error is false`() {
        val email = DataDummy.userEmail
        val password = DataDummy.userPassword

        val expectedUser = MutableLiveData<Event<UserModel>>()
        expectedUser.value = Event(dummyUser)

        val expectedError = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>>()
        expectedError.value = Event(false)

        `when`(viewModel.userLogin(email, password)).thenReturn(expectedUser)

        val actualUser = viewModel.userLogin(email, password).getOrAwaitValue()
        val actualError = viewModel.error.getOrAwaitValue()

        Mockito.verify(repository).userLogin(email, password)
        assertNotNull(actualUser.peekContent())
        assertFalse(actualError.peekContent())
    }
}
```

### Error Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mankart.mankgram.ui.authentication.AuthenticationViewModel.userLogin(AuthenticationViewModel.kt:32)
    at com.mankart.mankgram.ui.authentication.AuthenticationViewModelTest.when userLogin should return user response when email and password are valid and error is false(AuthenticationViewModelTest.kt:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:100)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:107)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:41)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


com.mankart.mankgram.ui.authentication.AuthenticationViewModelTest > when userLogin should return user response when email and password are valid and error is false FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at AuthenticationViewModelTest.kt:46
1 test completed, 1 failed
> Task :app:testDebugUnitTest FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/asus/AndroidStudioProjects/Submission/Mankgram/app/build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2m 29s
```

Comment: Could you please put the exception into your question?

Comment: I have put the error exception